# How to Remove PHP Array Implode Character from Beginning of String

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am working on a project that requires imploding an array with character separation. I have successfully used `join` and `implode` interchangeably in other parts of the project, but I can't get it to work in this section.

```
$dbQuery = "SELECT ftc.*, fc.name
            FROM facilities f
            LEFT JOIN facility_to_category ftc ON f.fid = ftc.fid
            LEFT JOIN facility_categories fc ON ftc.cid = fc.cid
            WHERE f.listing_year = '2011'
                AND fc.parent_cid = '2'
              AND f.fid = ('".$listing_fid."')";
    $dbResult = $dbc->query($dbQuery,__FILE__,__LINE__);
    $num_results = $dbc->num_rows($dbResult);
    echo '<h3>Demographics</h3>
    <div>';
    while($catdata = $dbc->fetch($dbResult)) {
        $demographics = array();
        $demographic_names = array('',trim($catdata->name));
        $demographics = implode('  '.chr(149).'   ',$demographic_names);   
        print $demographics; 
    }
```

The result is this:

```
Demographics
• Affluent • Children • Hard-to-Reach • Parents
```

instead of

```
Demographics
Affluent • Children • Hard-to-Reach • Parents
```

I've tried using double quotes instead of single quotes around '.chr(149).'. I've tried using commas or bars or just spaces. I've tried different ways of trimming and not trimming `$catdata->name`.

I also thought about trying string concatenation, but then I'll end up with an extra character at the end instead of the beginning. `Implode` or `join` seem the better way to go.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `$demographic_names[0]` blank? Also, why are you setting `$demographics = array();` then almost immediately turning it into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, everyone, for your help! I ended up reformatting the query and array. Here is the final code:

```
$dbQuery = "SELECT ftc.*, fc.name
            FROM facilities f
            LEFT JOIN facility_to_category ftc ON f.fid = ftc.fid
            LEFT JOIN facility_categories fc ON ftc.cid = fc.cid
            WHERE f.listing_year = '2011'
                AND fc.parent_cid = '2'
              AND f.fid = ('".$listing_fid."')";
    $dbResult = $dbc->query($dbQuery,__FILE__,__LINE__);
    $num_results = $dbc->num_rows($dbResult);
    echo '<h3>Demographics</h3>
    <div>';
    while($catdata = $dbc->fetch($dbResult)) {
        $demographics = array();
        if (is_array($demographics)) {
        $demographic_names[] = trim($catdata->name);
        }
    }
    $demographics = join('  '.chr(149).'   ',$demographic_names);           
    print $demographics;
```

The result is:

```
Demographics
Affluent • Children • Hard-to-Reach • Parents
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but why not use

```
$demographics_names = array();
while($catdata = $dbc->fetch($dbResult)) {
    array_push($demographics_names, trim($catdata->name));
}
$demographics = implode('  '.chr(149).'   ',$demographic_names);   
print $demographics;
```

Comment: Moving the implode outside of the while statement helped!

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting a blank element into the array that you're imploding:

```
$demographic_names = array('',trim($catdata->name));
                           ^--- here
```

Comment: Thank you -- I tried removing that, but it somehow prevented the join character from working at all. The result was AffluentChildrenHard-to-ReachParents

Comment: Well this is because you only have 1 element in your `$demographic_names` array.  `implode()` will only put the join character between 2 elements.  Use @JeromeWAGNER's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a blank `demographic_name`.  Use `array_filter` on the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

Check the first array is empty.

```
while($catdata = $dbc->fetch($dbResult)) {
    $demographics = array();
    $demographic_names = array('',trim($catdata->name));
    if(!empty($demographic_names))
    {
      $demographics = implode('  '.chr(149).'   ',$demographic_names);   
      print $demographics; 
    }
}
```